# What is the problem if images from Kubernetes PVC are not accessible after redeploy?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, strapi, kubernetes-pvc

I am using Strapi within a digital-ocean Kubernetes cluster. The public folder images are handled by a persistent volume claim(PVC). After a redeploy, the images are visible within Strapi and also from http://api.mywebsite.com/uploads/blabla.jpg. An Imaginary image processor located within the same cluster returns a 404 Error when trying to get the same images from Strapi.

What might be the cause of this?

I have tried to build an initContainer like written here https://medium.com/faun/digitalocean-kubernetes-and-volume-permissions-820f46598965 but it did not help.

```
initContainers:
  - name: data-permissions-fix
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/chmod","-R","777", "/backend/public/uploads"]
    volumeMounts:
      - name: backend-images
        mountPath: /backend/public/uploads
```

---

The flow is like this: frontend -> ingress -> image-processor (Fastify server) -> imaginary -> backend

Backend:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.18.0 ()
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: backend
  name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        image: backend
        name: backend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1337
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /backend/public/uploads
          name: backend-images
          readOnly: false
      initContainers:
      - name: data-permissions-fix
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/chmod","-R","777", "/backend/public/uploads"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: backend-images
          mountPath: /backend/public/uploads
      volumes:
      - name: backend-images
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: backend-images
      initContainers:
      - name: init-db
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nc -z db:5432; do echo waiting for db; sleep 2; done;']
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Backend PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: backend-images
  name: backend-images
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
  # persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
status: {}
```

Describe backend pod:

```
Name:               backend-5f-vhx48
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               pool-1-xveq/10.135.181.55
Start Time:         Thu, 27 Jun 2019 19:07:31 +0200
Labels:             io.kompose.service=backend
                    pod-template-hash=5f9fb4fbb6
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.244.1.92
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/backend-5f9fbb6
Init Containers:
  init-db:
    Container ID:  docker://e4728305d970fb2d76f1f203271d3ce902a5ef56
    Image:         busybox
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://busybox@sha256:7a4d4ed96e15da96906910d57fc4a13210160
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      until nc -z db:5432; do echo waiting for db; sleep 2; done;
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Thu, 27 Jun 2019 19:07:39 +0200
      Finished:     Thu, 27 Jun 2019 19:07:39 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-fl98h (ro)
Containers:
  backend:
    Container ID:   docker://b42bea24655d3d40e59985f8fff96bce
    Image:          backend
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://backend@sha25663765ef8841b45e4717f047b71446c1058d2
    Port:           1337/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 27 Jun 2019 19:07:41 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
    Mounts:
      /usr/src/backend/public/uploads from backend-images-teuberkohlhoff (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-fl98h (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  backend-images-teuberkohlhoff:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  backend-images
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-fl98h:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-flh72
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Describe PVC:

```
Name:          backend-images
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  do-block-storage
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-de757a78-8b8a-364b3aed3
Labels:        io.kompose.service=backend-images
Annotations:   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                 {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"io.kompose.service":"ba...
               pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: dobs.csi.digitalocean.com
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      1Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Events:        <none>
Mounted By:    backend-5f-vhx48
```

Image-processor:

```
const imaginary = require('imaginary');
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true });

const imageServer = 'http://imaginary:9000/';

fastify.get('*', async (request, reply) => {
  const {
    filename, type: format, width: imageWidth, url: imageUrl,
  } = request.query;

  const imageStream = imaginary()
    .server(imageServer)
    .resize({ width: imageWidth, url: imageUrl, type: format })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Cannot resize the image:', err);
    });

  reply
    .header('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${filename}.${format}"`)
    .header('Content-Type', `image/${format}`)
    .send(imageStream);
});

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen(9009, '0.0.0.0');
    fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${fastify.server.address().port}`);
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error('ERROR', err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
start();
```

The frontend img-url is

> http://imagehandling.domain.com/b2b36f31caa9d8f6/320/title.webp?type=webp&width=320&url=http://backend:1337/uploads/b2b36f31caa9d8f6.jpg&filename=title

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions that need to be made here. Help eliminate them by editing the question to provide: Deployment / pod specs for the application and PVC, the `describe` output of the PVC, nodes, and pods, information on the image processor (how is it trying to pull images?), any log output from both your application and the image processor.

Comment: What's the endpoint that the image processor is hitting compared to the endpoint of strapi?

Comment: Thank you for both your interests. I added more information to my original question. Hope this helps.

Comment: please could you share your dockerfile to build the strapi image?

Comment: @webdev I have added the Dockerfile to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, it was my error. The Ingress controller was hitting the wrong URL. I will just leave the question in case others are searching for how to setup image processing.

---

@webdev asked for the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/backend

RUN echo "unsafe-perm = true" >> ~/.npmrc

RUN apk add --no-cache \
  autoconf \
  automake \
  gcc \
  libc-dev \
  libtool \
  make \
  nasm \
  zlib-dev

RUN npm install -g strapi@beta

COPY . .

# COPY strapi.sh ./
RUN chmod +x ./strapi.sh

EXPOSE 1337

# COPY healthcheck.js ./
HEALTHCHECK --interval=15s --timeout=5s --start-period=30s \
  CMD node /usr/src/api/healthcheck.js

CMD ["./strapi.sh"]
```

Strapi.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ea

_stopStrapi() {
  echo "Stopping strapi"
  kill -SIGINT "$strapiPID"
  wait "$strapiPID"
}

trap _stopStrapi TERM INT

cd /usr/src/app/backend

APP_NAME=${APP_NAME:-strapi-app}
DATABASE_CLIENT=${DATABASE_CLIENT:-mongo}
DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST:-localhost}
DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT:-27017}
DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME:-strapi}
DATABASE_SRV=${DATABASE_SRV:-false}
EXTRA_ARGS=${EXTRA_ARGS:-}

FRESH_BOOTSTRAP=false

if [ ! -f "$APP_NAME/package.json" ]
then
    strapi new ${APP_NAME} --dbclient=$DATABASE_CLIENT --dbhost=$DATABASE_HOST --dbport=$DATABASE_PORT --dbsrv=$DATABASE_SRV --dbname=$DATABASE_NAME --dbusername=$DATABASE_USERNAME --dbpassword=$DATABASE_PASSWORD --dbssl=$DATABASE_SSL --dbauth=$DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE $EXTRA_ARGS
    strapi new "${APP_NAME}" \
    "--dbclient=$DATABASE_CLIENT" \
    "--dbhost=$DATABASE_HOST" \
    "--dbport=$DATABASE_PORT" \
    "--dbsrv=$DATABASE_SRV" \
    "--dbname=$DATABASE_NAME" \
    "--dbusername=$DATABASE_USERNAME" \
    "--dbpassword=$DATABASE_PASSWORD" \
    "--dbssl=$DATABASE_SSL" \
    "--dbauth=$DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE" \
    $EXTRA_ARGS \
    --dbforce

    FRESH_BOOTSTRAP=true
elif [ ! -d "$APP_NAME/node_modules" ]
then
    npm install --prefix "./$APP_NAME"

    FRESH_BOOTSTRAP=true
fi

cd $APP_NAME

if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "production" ]
then
    strapi start &
else
    strapi develop &
fi

strapiPID=$!
wait "$strapiPID"
```